# Json array can contain objects that have a Name containing a backslash

Tags: c#, .net, json, backslash

I have a Json containing for example Students that have a Name and ID, the Name can contain backslashes, ex: Dan\iel.
I am using this json as a datasource for a custom listView and my problem is that names containing backslases are not displayed correctly, ex: instead of Dan\iel I get Dan el and a JavaScript error.
My solution was to replace every backshash in the name with \, I am doing this on the server:

```
return (from c in datasource
    select new Student()
    {
        ID = c.ID,
        Name = c.Name.Replace(@"\",@"\\"),
    }).ToList();
```

datasource is a table that I'm reading form the DB  and has all students.
This works, but i'm wondering if there's a way of doing this in a more elegant way.

Comment: Your solution for serializing to JSON should handle this. How are you serializing the list to JSON?

Comment: _datasource = $.parseJSON(datasource);

Comment: When ever u are returning value to the json then also replace the "/" with "//". I have faced the similar problem and it is solved like this.

Comment: How are you serializing this to JSON?